# Localhost port aliased

Tags: localhost, hosts, etc

I wanted to use `/etc/hosts` to define "aliases" for multiple services localhosted like:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.0.1:8080 machin
127.0.0.1:8081 truc
```

But it doesn't seem to work, surely because `/etc/hosts` has nothing to do with ports

Is there a way to alias these ports ?

Comment: How about first specifying those port under [vhost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) I never tried that, just a suggestion ;)

Comment: I already do that for my web applications. But I still have to type `localhost:port/path` in the browser. I mean it doesn't do the alias job.